# Why all drives are converting to dynamic when I created one

Tags: windows-7, dynamic-disk, basic-disk

I just installed Windows 7 Ultimate on my new Lenovo G570 laptop. I left some unallocated space so as to create few dynamic drives as there is a limit for primary.

So, when I created a dynamic drive from unallocated space, windows changed all drive from primary to dynamic including the drive which contains OS. Thus when I rebooted my system, windows couldn't start.

Why  this is happening, is there any problem with my PC?

Comment: Basic vs. dynamic is on a whole-drive basis - you don't make dynamic drives, you make dynamic DISKS.  How are you trying to partition it in the first place that you need to do this, on a laptop nonetheless?

Answer (score 3):

### The major problem lies in your understanding of the concepts.

- **Partitions may be *primary* or *secondary*** in the old PC/AT (a.k.a. "MBR" or "MS-DOS") partitioning scheme.  (In the new EFI partitioning scheme, there's no such distinction and no need for such a distinction.)

  Secondary partitions live within container (primary) partitions.  Sometimes — and somewhat confusingly — they are known as *logical drives* and the container partitions as *extended partitions*.
- **Discs may be *dynamic* or *basic***.

  Basic discs use the partitioning scheme (be it PC/AT or EFI) as-is.  Dynamic discs overlay that with a Microsoft proprietary logical volume management system.

You've converted a basic disc to a dynamic disc when what you actually wanted to do was create a container partition with some secondary partitions in it because you'd hit the four primary partition limit of the old-style partitioning scheme.  To get where you originally wanted to go, you'll need to convert your dynamic disc back to being a basic disc once more, and create secondary partitions in a container partition instead.

My educated guess, given that you've provided nowhere near enough information for diagnosis, is that Windows will not boot *probably* because you've changed the identity of your [boot volume](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/boot-and-system-volumes.html).  But the only Microsoft-sanctioned conversion method from dynamic to basic involves wiping your entire disc and starting again.  So fixing the problems with booting is pointless.  You'll be wiping and reinstalling *anyway*.

Yes, some people will say that they've hand-edited their old-style partition table with a hex editor to convert a dynamic disc back to a basic disc.  This will only work in a quite limited range of circumstances, and mess things up quite royally the rest of the time.  It's not something that I'd recommend to someone who hasn't yet got primary/secondary versus dynamic/basic straight.  ☺

#### Further reading

- Microsoft corporation (2000). [*Basic and Dynamic Discs*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc976789.aspx).  TechNet.
- Microsoft corporation (2007-12-01). [*Basic Storage Versus Dynamic Storage in Windows XP*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314343).  ID 314343. Microsoft Support KnowledgBase.
- Microsoft corporation (2004-07-14). [*How To Convert to Basic and Dynamic Disks in Windows XP Professional*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309044).  ID 309044.  Microsoft Support KnowledgBase.
- Microsoft corporation (2005-01-21). [*Dynamic disks and volumes*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc757696%28WS.10%29.aspx).  TechNet.
- Microsoft corporation (2005-01-21). [*Change a dynamic disk back to a basic disk*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc776315%28WS.10%29.aspx).  TechNet.